# How to store result of SQL query on Nest.js server between client requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, backend, typeorm

I have Node.js (with Nest.js) backend app. On my client app (React) I have infinite scroll component and with every scroll to the bottom, client send request to backend to fetch the data. That request invoke database query with TypeORM, but that query takes a lot of time to fetch data from database, mainly because of huge size of columns - couple of millions of characters (I tested it with smaller columns size and everything was quick enough).

How can I fix it? I can't move that huge columns to frontend side, because it crashes the browser. Is there some way to keep result of that database query between requests from client?

Here's my TypeORM query that takes about 10 seconds if column `select_list` contain couple of millions of characters.

```
await this.correlationsRepository
            .createQueryBuilder('c')
            .select('c.select_list')
            .where({
                id: correlationId
            })
            .execute();
```

Comment: sounds like you want to use caching - there is a nice writeup on the official NestJS docs on how to achieve this: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the size of records and structure of table.
So I suggest multiple candidates.

---

## Pagination

If you can only change the query, use pagination. And if the records in database changed easily (added, deleted, modified, whatever) use cursor based pagination.

In most case, using offset-based pagination using [limit](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#adding-limit-expression) and [offset](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#adding-offset-expression)

But if the records in your database changed easily as I mentioned before, use [cursor based pagination](https://dev.to/jackmarchant/offset-and-cursor-pagination-explained-b89) like this.

## Caching

If you can't modify the table's structure and there are available resource for allocate another storage, consider the caching like [@GoranLegenda mentioned in comment.](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching) Using another in-memory key value storage like `redis` also could solve this problem.

---

Hope this answer maybe helpful for you.